# Language.TryParse Method use in sitecore point of view?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2

Just to ask one things.

What is the use of below methods in sitecore context.

```
Language.TryParse(string value, out bool);
```

As this method belongs to `Sitecore.Kernal` library so not able to see the code however in my case it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to the `bool Language.TryParse(string value, out Language result)` method, right? It'll give you a `Language` object if the provided `value` is a locale, such as `en-US`, registered in Sitecore. There are some more caveats within that method. You can read the source of it using a reflection tool, such as dotPeek.

Since there may be different languages in different Sitecore databases, it's usually more suitable to use for example `LanguageManager.GetLanguage(string name, Database database)`. It'll return the `Language` object if exists, or null if it's not available in the given database.

Comment: So as per thought, this is not right method for use.